# Phone (iPhone/Android) and Javascript compatibility

Tags: jquery, android, iphone, mobile

Are there chart where I can determine the compatibility of javascript on phones like iPhone and Android. And Are there guidelines in developing javascript app for mobile? like how big should the file be? Can I use javascript libraries (eg. jQuery)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you want to use javaScript you should try [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official compatibility link. For Android it depends on the version of Android and which browser are you referring to.

I found some basic attempts at testing this compatibility http://www.quirksmode.org/m/table.html

Comment: Not sure I'd call PPK's work (the Quirks Mode page linked above) "basic" it's pretty exhaustive and definitely the best resource out there. In addition to that, Apple has [well documented developer pages about Mobile Safari](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/Introduction/Introduction.html). As mentioned, the main issue with Android is fragmentation.